# Python: random function from locals() with defined prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, locals

I'm working on a textbased adventure and now want to run a random function.
All adventure function are "adv" followed by a 3 digit number.
If I run go() I get back :

```
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

This is because allAdv is still empty. If i run go() line by line in the shell it works but not in the function. What did I miss?

```
import fight
import char
import zoo
import random

#runs a random adventure
def go():
    allAdv=[]
    for e in list(locals().keys()):
        if e[:3]=="adv":
            allAdv.append(e)
    print(allAdv)
    locals()[random.choice(allAdv)]()


#rat attacks out of the sewer
def adv001():
    print("All of a sudden an angry rat jumps out of the sewer right beneath your feet. The small, stinky animal aggressivly flashes his teeth.")
    fight.report(zoo.rat)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "run go() line by line in the shell" ?

Comment: I went into the shell and copy/pasted every line from the go() function (and the for loop as a block) in the same order and tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mainly due to the scope issue, when you invoke `locals()` in `go()`, it only prints out the local variables `allDev` defined in this function:

```
locals().keys()  # ['allDev']
```

But if you type the following line by line in the shell, `locals()` do include `adv001` since they are at the same level in this case.

```
def adv001():
    print("All of a sudden an angry rat jumps out of the sewer right beneath your feet. The small, stinky animal aggressivly flashes his teeth.")
    fight.report(zoo.rat)

allAdv=[]
print locals().keys()  #  ['adv001', '__builtins__', 'random', '__package__', '__name__', '__doc__']
for e in list(locals().keys()):
    if e[:3]=="adv":
        allAdv.append(e)
print(allAdv)
locals()[random.choice(allAdv)]()
```

If you really want to get those function variables in `go()`, you might consider change `locals().keys()` to `globals().keys()`